# Are Optical Detectors/Phototransistors safe?

Tags: infrared, phototransistor

Are Optical Detector/Phototransistor such as [QRD1114](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/246) *safe*?

The QRD1114 emits [infrared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared), which high exposure to, could be [harmful](http://www.ishn.com/articles/94815-dangers-of-overexposure-to-ultraviolet-infrared-and-high-energy-visible-light).

If I had a matrix of 10 x 10 QRD1114's, and a user must stand in-front of the matrix waving his hand, how do I go about safety and limiting usage so that the user does not get overexposed to infrared?

How would you label such device (matrix) safe to use?

Comment: A 40 Watt lightbulb will emit more IR, and I haven't been killed by one of th

Comment: Be very careful when you use an IR TV remote, too... When directed towards the brains, it can kill people. Or mabe what kills people's brains is what is shown on most TV channels, I don't know.

Comment: To put things into perspective, many security cameras illuminate and detect in the IR spectrum. That way an area can be illuminated to the IR detector, but not to the eye. And as far as I'm aware there's no craze over security cameras harming people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What makes you think that a photodetector emits light? A photodetector absorbs light and produces current.

The device you linked is not a photodetector, it is a coupled LED with a photodetector.

While LEDs can be made bright enough to be hazardous, but it is fairly difficult and expensive to do that. Roughly, it takes more than about 1 mW, emitted in a very cone tight enough to all enter the user's pupil, to be even possibly hazardous (and at that level you'd need the user to willfully stare at the beam for several minutes to injure themselves).

The fact that the datasheet provides no output power or eye safety information at all is a good indicator (because Fairchild is a reputable company --- I wouldn't say the same about a random E-Bay listing for a laser pointer) that this device produces nowhere near that much power.

> If I had a matrix of 10 x 10 QRD1114's, and a user must stand in-front of the matrix waving his hand, how do I go about safety and limiting usage so that the user does not get overexposed to infrared?

Now you're talking about 100x the power of a single device. I think this probably justifies getting some radiometry equipment and measuring the actual output power of your devices (or your array). If the output flux is more than about 0.5 mW per mm<sup>2</sup> (or could get that high under foreseeable fault conditions), you might want to rethink your idea. Mitigating measures could include reducing the forward current applied to the LEDs, or placing a barrier to prevent your users getting close enough to the emitters to risk injury.

Answer (score 2):

At 1.7V, the LED in the QRD1114 consumes 20mA, for a total power consumption of 34mW. If we assume that *all* of this power is dissipated as IR then 100 of them would generate 3.4W. If we put a 500mL bottle of water at room temperature in front of them then it would take *over 13 hours* for it to reach boiling, assuming that the *only* energy transfer was from IR to the water.

And since both assumptions in the previous paragraph are ***utterly insane***, there is no issue.

Comment: A human eyeball is maybe 2 or 3 mL, though.

Comment: Which translates to about 3.6 seconds per kelvin. Assuming they're all focused on the eyeball.